# ¿Cómo se le dice al que deposita dinero en una cuenta bancaria?

Tags: vocabulario, finanzas

Me preguntaba cuál sería el término correcto para designar a esta persona. Sé que se dice "destinatario" al que recibe el dinero de una cuenta, pero no sé cómo se llama al que deposita dinero a una cuenta.

Comment: Yo creo que busca la palabra el/la depositante or el/la impositor(a).

Comment: Sip, eso mismo creo yo. Estaba pensando en "emisor" pero... no cuadra, ya que tendría que ser un mensaje, no una cantidad de dinero.

Comment: Quizás *pagador* también, si es una cuenta ajena.

Comment: Faltaría añadir un acento a "como" en el título de la pregunta y otro a "se" del verbo "saber".

Comment: @Charo creo que el límite de 6 caracteres no aplica si editas también el título.

Comment: No lo sé, @wimi: ya haré la prueba en otra ocasión.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En los bancos de España, el emisor de una transferencia bancaria se suele llamar **ordenante**. De *[Finanzas para todos](https://www.finanzasparatodos.es/es/productosyservicios/productosbancariosoperativos/serviciostransferencias.html)*:

> Una transferencia bancaria es la operación por la que una persona o entidad (el ordenante) da instrucciones a su entidad bancaria para que envíe, con cargo a una cuenta suya, una determinada cantidad de dinero a la cuenta de otra persona o empresa (el beneficiario)

[Algunos bancos](http://www.padul.org/detalle-de-la-noticia/?tx_news_pi1%5Bnews%5D=3014&tx_news_pi1%5Bcontroller%5D=News&tx_news_pi1%5Baction%5D=detail&cHash=39eb2d48533c654126ccb1756de561fa) utilizan esta palabra también para referirse a la persona que ingresa dinero en efectivo en una cuenta bancaria ajena. Por ejemplo, [el Banco Santander](https://santander.inbenta.com/?sessionId=t9drkj2ha6aqhdaarcp3vfi3h5&c=114) (cursivas mías):

> **Ingreso en cuenta de uno de nuestros clientes**:
>
> [...]
>
> - Indica el *ordenante* y el concepto del ingreso, y pulsa "Continuar".

La operación de ingresar dinero en efectivo en una cuenta bancaria ajena se denomina **imposición de efectivo**. De [Expansión](https://www.expansion.com/diccionario-economico/imposicion-de-efectivo.html):

> 1. Entrega de dinero en efectivo por parte de una persona física o en nombre de una persona jurídica en una cuenta corriente o de ahorros de una institución financiera.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! Ahora que recuerdo creo que lo oí en alguna ocasión.